# How to populate edit form (one to many relationship laravel)

Tags: php, laravel-5, one-to-many

I have one form that adds data to two different tables (Articles & Deals). An Article has many deals. A deal has one Article. I can't work out how to populate the edit form with the data from the Deals table. I know I'm doing it wrong but at the moment it just populates the edit form with a long array. I think I need to change the Articles Controller and form value variable. At the moment I just have $deals on every deal day.

I'm using Laravel 5.

The Articles Table has: id, title, image, description, address.
The Deals table has: id, dealname, article_id, dayID.

FORM:

```
{!! Form::model($article, ['route' => ['articleUpdate_path', $article->id], 'files' => true, 'method' => 'PATCH']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('title','TITLE') !!}
    {!! Form::text('title', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    {!! $errors->first('title','<p class="error">:message</p>')!!}

    {!! Form::label('image','PHOTO') !!}
    {!! Form::file('image', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('description','DESCRIPTION') !!}
    {!! Form::textarea('description', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('dealname','Monday') !!}
    {!! Form::text('dealname[]', $deals, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('dealname','Tuesday') !!}
    {!! Form::text('dealname[]', $deals, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('dealname','Wednesday') !!}
    {!! Form::text('dealname[]', $deals,null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('address','ADDRESS') !!}
    {!! Form::text('address', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

ARTICLES CONTROLLER

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $article = Article::find($id);
    $deals = Deal::lists('dealname');
    return view('articles.edit', compact('article', 'deals'));
}
```

ARTICLE MODEL

```
class Article extends Model
{
    public function deals()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Deal');
    }  
protected $fillable = array('title', 'photo', 'description', 'address'); 
}
```

DEAL MODEL

```
class Deal extends Model
{
    public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Article')->withTimestamps();
    }
    protected $fillable = array('dealname', 'article_id', 'dayID'); 
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't your controller method fetch the deals as `$article = Article::find($id)->with('deals');`? Then in your view, use a `@foreach ($article->deals as $deal)` to loop through them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Laravel 5 - Query Builder documentation:

> $roles = DB::table('roles')->lists('title');
>
> This method will return an array of role titles.

Since you are simply returning the $deals variable, your output will be the array returned by the above.

In order to output the individual deals, you should use a "foreach" loop within the view to output the specific variables of each deal (as QuickDanger mentions in his comment).